# Searching a Dictionary

Tags: java, for-loop, dictionary, hashmap

I have been trying to improve my Java skills, and decided to create a Noughts and Crosses game. I'm trying to implement winning conditions, so the game can tell if the "ai" or human has won, and end the game.

The data is stored in a HashMap as  key value pairs. The integer being the position and the String being what it contains. The string will be `""`, `"O"` or `"X"`.

Integer representing positions:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Code showing database initialization:

```
Map<Integer, String> database = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Anyway, I am trying to work out the best way to search through this dictionary, checking to see any of the following win conditions:

- 3 "O" or "X" Strings in positions 1, 2, 3 <--Horizontally
- 3 "O" or "X" Strings in positions 4, 5, 6 <--Horizontally
- 3 "O" or "X" Strings in positions 7, 8, 9 <--Horizontally
- 3 "O" or "X" Strings in positions 1, 4, 7 <--Vertically
- 3 "O" or "X" Strings in positions 2, 5, 8 <--Vertically
- 3 "O" or "X" Strings in positions 3, 6, 9 <--Vertically
- 3 "O" or "X" Strings in positions 1, 5, 9 <--Diagonally
- 3 "O" or "X" Strings in positions 3, 5, 7 <--Diagonally

Will I have to do a large nested if statement, or case sets, or is there a way I can more efficiently loop through this?

Comment: Isn't it `Noughts` and crosses?

Comment: Updated with correct spelling, cheers.

Comment: How efficient do you want it to be? What is your performance requirement? Do you really think it matters for 9 items? What have you tried? Was it slow?

Comment: A `Map` is a rather odd choice, but it'll work regardless. You can store all the winning combinations as 3 numbers, as you already have, then loop through them all, checking to see if all the three values in the indexes match. Then determine who won by checking any of those values. I'd recommend creating a `checkWin(int[] indexes)` method which would check all 3 indexes and return true/false on whether they match.

Comment: Well I want to learn how to make it more efficient, and nested ifs are costly in development time (if not processing power).

Comment: That makes sense, if you put that as an answer Kayaman I'll mark it correct. :)

Comment: You can also give all your fields on the board a value. 1 if X, -1 if O and 0 if empty. Then after each turn, count the values on the rows, columns and diagonals and see if there is a -3 or +3 value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Map is a rather odd choice, but it'll work regardless. You can store all the winning combinations as 3 numbers, as you already have, then loop through them all, checking to see if all the three values in the indexes match. Then determine who won by checking any of those values.

I'd recommend creating a `checkWin(int[] indexes)` method which would check all 3 indexes and return true/false on whether they match. Then loop through all your pre-made winning combinations to check for a win.